# Quickly Copy UV's from one face to another

Tags: uv, workflow, uv-image-editor

I am looking for a way to increase the speed of my workflow. For the task at hand I will be using custom textures with replicated UVs across the same model. In other words, the walls will reference the same UV, as will the floor tiles, etc. Right now I have to select a face—let's say a floor tile—resize the uvs until they match the correct area of the texture, and then repeat the process for every other floor tile. It's a little too time consuming. I was wondering if there is a way that I could simply copy the UV rectangle of one floor tile, and copy it to the rest. Here is a picture to further articulate my wishes:

[image]

Does anyone have any tips to increase the copying of UVs?

Answer (score 10):

Use this add-on:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Copy_Paste_UVs

[image]

You could also just unwrap one, then use an array modifier to duplicate it down the row, then remove doubles.

Comment: This add-on had been renamed to "Magic UV", [new project page](https://github.com/nutti/Magic-UV), stable version is included with Blender and can be activated in Preferences -> Add-Ons.

Comment: What surprised me is that when multiple faces are selected, "paste" command applies UV to all of them — very convenient!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an exact solution to this, but I did discover a quick way to configure the UV's by hand. All you have to do is look at the face that you want to alter UV's for, select it, press U, and then "Project from View". The UV quad/triangle will show up with the correct orientation(assuming you were looking at it the correct way)and all you will have to do then is drag the corners of the uv into place on the desired texture area. This greatly increased my speed when it came to texturing models.

If anyone has a better suggestion for actually copying UV data, I would love to hear it still.

Comment: By creating the parts of an object and texturing them before joining into one and duplicating, you can save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

In *Object Mode* select the object, you wish to copy the UV order to, hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and select the object you wish to copy the UV order from, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd> and choose *Transfer UV Maps*.

Comment: This will overwrite whole UV layer of the object which can be unexpected if only several faces were supposed to get the same UV map as in the source object

Comment: Right. I didn't read the header. It's what I use all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use this addon tool?

**Align / Distribute UV**
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/UV_Align_Distribution

It should help with scaling the faces to fit your last scaled uv face.

Answer (score -1):

In the **3D view** of the uv editor, under the uv tab you can find copy/paste uv>copy>default

This will copy the coordinates of your selected face.

Then select your next face and choose copy/paste uv>paste>default to paste those coordinates to the face.

Strangely, this function is **not** found under the UV tab in the **image view** of the UV editor, which is
where you would expect to find it.

Comment: This is only if you have the magic uv addon installed.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I forgot to mention that!